# Exclude folder from APK in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I've included a production folder in the root of my project, after building the APK and opening it as an archive, I've noticed that the production folder has not been included.

Am I right/safe to assume that any un-referenced files/folders are automatically excluded from the APK or should I be using some sort of configuration file to specify an exclusion list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would phrase it more as "only stuff in `src/` might ever get included in an APK, for a conventional Android Studio project".

If you create random other directories, those will be ignored, unless you specifically do something in `build.gradle` to try using them (e.g., as an alternative location for `assets/`).

IOW, the contents of an APK come from a whitelist, not a blacklist.

Comment: I've even tried placing it in `app/src/main/res` and it is still excluded. I suppose the "APK come from a whitelist, not a blacklist." explains this.

Comment: @sudoman: Right. You cannot invent new resource directories. That's part of my "might ever get included" phrase. There are specific locations for putting files; stuff outside those locations will either be ignored or might cause a build error. So, if you put that stuff in `app/src/main/assets/`, *then* it would get included in the APK, because that's the role of `assets/`: arbitrary stuff you want packaged in the APK.